# Sitecore shared field toggle does not propagate to other environments

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

After creating different templates and moving them to different environment through Sitecore packages , we decided that some fields need to be shared. Those changes were made on dev environment and propagated them on test environment. 
The issue is that when adding a new version on test environment on a language the values from the shared fields are not being copied . If the shared field value is being setup directly on the test environment the values are being copied.

Any ideas why this might happen and what's the fix?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are propagating the template change between environments, and what version of Sitecore you are on?

Comment: with sitecore packages. 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you propagate these field changes?

The problem is; when you toggle a field in and out of "shared", a background task starts in Sitecore that will move field values around. Under the hood, Sitecore stores field values in 3 separate tables - SharedFields, VersionedFields and UnversionedFields.

Depending on how you pushed this change to your other environments, this background task might not have executed correctly.

Sitecore describes this problem here. I've never tried their fix myself.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/045873